# Downloading Specific Filenames with FTP

Tags: linux, download, ftp, mget

I have about 1,000,000 files and I should do FTP to get some specific files.
in 1,000,000 files with the name of ML0000000-ML1000000 i want specific file starts ML00002222 till ML00899999.
can anyone help me how to edir mget for ftp ?

```
######login to FTP server:@@@@@
ftp -inv 172.0.0.1
user Codegirl $$$$
#######cd to ftp server#########
cd /root/desktop
######cd to local PC#############
lcd /root/myfile
*mget ML*   ??? (how can i change it to specific file name?)*
```

Comment: It's not easy to turn numeric ranges like this into wildcards.

Comment: yes i know i hope any one can has a solution for this :-(

Comment: Use a programming language rather than the interactive ftp program.

Comment: Then you can write a `for` loop to iterate over the numeric range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was me I'd use a loop and wget.

```
cd /root/myfile

for i in $(seq -f "%08g" 2222 899999)

do
  wget --username=un --password=pw ftp://172.0.0.1/root/desktop/ML${i}
done
```

This does require wget to reconnect each time, it's going to take time anyway so go and run the script and grab a cup of tea. I use loops like this all the time and it works well.

Comment: this works but do not download the file i see the file which counts but the file does not copied! also it is slow. is it any way to do it faster!